# Using OleDB requires what?

Tags: c#, oledb

I am confused about the requirements for using OleDB.

Within an application I read XLS files with OleDB. After that I publish my project with ClickOnce (Visual Stuido 2012, .NET 4.0). But will the application work on a Windows System with ONLY .NET 4.0 installed? Or do others have to install MS Office because of the internal usage of OleDB?

Comment: It was deprecated 13 years ago.  But my Windows 8.1 machine still has c:\windows\syswow64\msjetoledb40.dll preinstalled.  Microsoft has to live forever with every mistake they made :)

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I did not know it was deprecated, so I am wondering what the current 'standard' way to read read XLS files is?

Comment: Since, microsoft Excel moved from the proprietary .xls to more open standard format .xlsx, there are various libraries and tools that supports processing of Excel files. But still need OleDB for working with the xls files.

Answer (score 0):

OLEDB is an API for access data source.

- In order to use it you need an **OLE DB Provider**.
- An **OLE DB Provider** is simply a COM object.

You will likely have a number of OLE DB provider COM classes already registered on your machine:

```
| Name                                                         | VersionIndependentProgID            | ProgID                   | clsid                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|--------------------------|----------------------------------------|
| Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server                     | SQLOLEDB                            | SQLOLEDB.1               | {0C7FF16C-38E3-11d0-97AB-00C04FC2AD98} |
| Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 9.0          | MSOLAP                              | MSOLAP.3                 | {176941F9-18E8-47D6-860D-006FF2655608} |
| Microsoft OLE DB Provider For Data Mining Services           | MSDMine                             | MSDMine.1                | {2CB6C2D3-DD7C-11D2-AFE4-00105A994724} |
| MSDataShape                                                  | MSDataShape                         | MSDataShape.1            | {3449A1C8-C56C-11D0-AD72-00C04FC29863} |
| SQL Server Native Client 11.0                                | SQLNCLI11                           | SQLNCLI11.1              | {397C2819-8272-4532-AD3A-FB5E43BEAA39} |
| Microsoft.WINDOWS.SQLLITE.OLEDB.4.0                          |                                                                | {3A5B4772-7946-4E58-9310-B0D423749C1D} |
| Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider |                                     | Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 | {3BE786A0-0366-4F5C-9434-25CF162E475E} |
| OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services             |                                     | ADsDSOObject             | {549365d0-ec26-11cf-8310-00aa00b505db} |
| Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Search                         | Search.CollatorDSO                  | Search.CollatorDSO.1     | {9E175B8B-F52A-11D8-B9A5-505054503030} |
| Microsoft OLE DB Provider for OLAP Services 8.0              | MSOLAP                              | MSOLAP.2                 | {A07CCD0C-8148-11D0-87BB-00C04FC33942} |
| Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers                   | MSDASQL                             | MSDASQL.1                | {c8b522cb-5cf3-11ce-ade5-00aa0044773d} |
| Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider                            | Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB                 | Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0  | {dee35070-506b-11cf-b1aa-00aa00b8de95} |
| Microsoft OLE DB Simple Provider                             | MSDAOSP                             | MSDAOSP.1                | {dfc8bdc0-e378-11d0-9b30-0080c7e9fe95} |
| Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle                         | MSDAORA                             | MSDAORA.1                | {e8cc4cbe-fdff-11d0-b865-00a0c9081c1d} |
```

### OLE DB api was quite a pain

The API surface of OLE DB was very overly complicated; somebody went ham on:

```
//Create an SQL Server OLEDB Provider
IDBInitialize db = CreateComObject("SQLOLEDB");
db.Initialize();

IDBCreateCommand createCommand = (dataSource as IDBCreateSession).CreateSession(IDBCreateCommand);


ICommandText commandText = createCommand.CreateCommand();
commandText.CommandText = "SELECT 'Hello, world!'";
IRowSet rs = commandText.Execute();
```

### ADO made it easier

OLE DB is a very complex API. ADO came along and made it much easier.

```
Connection conn = new Connection();
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
conn.Open();

Recordset rs = new Recordset();
rs.ActiveConnection = conn;
rs.CommandText = "SELECT 'Hello, world!'";
rs.Open();
```

### ADO.net can use OLEDB providers

```
DbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
conn.Open();

DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'Hello, world!'";
IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

### All of these are using OLEDB

These are all examples of code (written on the fly, from memory), that **use** OLEDB.

The important thing is that you have to know which oledb **Provider** you want.

- **SQL Server**: `SQLOLEDB` *(ships with Windows)*
- **SQL Server (native client)**: `SQLNCLI` *(original, deprecated)*
- **SQL Server (native client)**: `SQLNCLI10` *(version 10, deprecated)*
- **SQL Server (native client)**: `SQLNCLI11` *(version 11, deprecated)*
- **SQL Server**: `MSOLEDBSQL` *(ships with SQL Server)*
- **Windows Search**: `Search.CollatorDSO`
- **Jet**: `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB`

Once you know what **Provider** you want, you have that in your [**Connection String**](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).

### To answer the question

What do you need to use OLEDB?

- a **provider**
- and you have to use it